# How to set "This is a no-reply email" in order confirmation email?

Tags: magento2, order-email, order-confirmation

I want to set `"This is a no-reply email, we will not see any emails sent to this address"` in order confirmation email so how can i do that ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Go to**

> `Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System`

- Under **Mail Sending Settings** make sure `Disable Email
  Communications` is set to `No`.

[image]
 - Got to **`Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails`**

Under

> General Settings -> `Asynchronous sending` to `Disable`

- Under `Order` tab `Enabled` to `Yes`

[image]

After that run this command

---

```
php bin/magento c:f
```